# How do I "include the executable in $PATH"?

Tags: command-line

I am having trouble understanding this instruction:

> include the executable in $PATH: sudo cp generator /usr/local/bin

What exactly do I have to enter in my terminal?

Comment: Welcome! It means that you are copying the executable `generator` (whatever it is) in (one of) the paths where the system store the executables, so them can be accesed system wide.

Comment: The command would be `sudo cp generator /usr/local/bin`, assuming you are in the path were "generator" is stored.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Problem is: i have some go files, the installation files for the generator. with "go get" and "go build" I think it worked. But I don"t know where the program is executable :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> include the executable in $PATH

This tells you what you need to achieve.  Your $PATH is the list of directories that are searched for executable programs by the shell when you try to run a command. If an executable program is in $PATH then you can run it by typing its name.

> :

The colon is used in English to introduce something.  In this case it introduces the command that you need to type

> `sudo cp generator /usr/local/bin`

This is the command.  `sudo` means "run the command as the superuser" [`cp`](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html) means "copy", usually where the following space-separated arguments are paths (locations in the file system) given in the order *origin destination*. `generator` is the name of a file in the current directory and `/usr/local/bin` is a system directory intended to contain executable programs. Most systems have `/usr/local/bin` in the default `$PATH`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it working :)